# How to make an element opaque in CSS without specifying the background?

Tags: html, css, z-index, background-color

Can I make an element opaque (impossible to see content underneath it), without specifying the background color (should "inherit" it from whatever is beneath it)?

Example:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 50px;
            z-index: 2; background: white;">
  Front div
</div>

<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
  Back div<br><br><br>top half obscured by front div
</div>
```

Gives the desired effect, but only because I set `background: white`. I'd like the effect to work without having to specify the background color, so it'd work anywhere. But by default, not having a background obviously doesn't work.

As written, if the page is `body { background: white; }`, then the effect works. But if the page is `body { background: green; }`, then the div is  still `white`, but I'd want it to be `green`.

Comment: You want to display something like: https://jsfiddle.net/w0agp80c/ ?

Comment: @ketan: yes, but without having to know the background of `body` (or any other elements that may be between it and the target element) beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to cover the element, you could modify the `opacity` of the element that you're trying to hide.

```css
body{
  background: green;
}
div{
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div> Hello world</div>
```

Comment: So, I'm not trying to hide the entire "Back div" element -- just the part underneath the "Front div". The end goal is to animate the front div expanding, but the effect doesn't work without knowing the background color: https://jsfiddle.net/9p1zkzgf/

Answer (score 0):

use inherit.

```css
body { background:green;}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 50px;
            z-index: 2;background:inherit">
  Front div
</div>

<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
  Back div<br><br><br>top half obscured by front div
</div>
```

Comment: `background` doesn't inherit normally, so if there are any elements between `body` and my target element, this won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/3hbf6dhz/

Comment: if that's the case, just start with your element. use jquery to keep going .parent() .parent() .parent() and on each level just css('background','inherit')

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-color: inherit;` in that div.
Note that by explicitly specifying the `background-color` property rather than the more general `background`, it will iirc apply the solid color inherited the parent element to the background (even if the parent element happens to be transparent, the inherited background colour will still have a value), thus making the element opaque.